# What is the equivalent field of PICASA to Solr?

Tags: xml, solr, xml-parsing, picasa

I want to convert PICASA xml into solr xml

This PICASA xml

```
<image>
  <isFirstImage>true</isFirstImage>
  <isPrevImage>false</isPrevImage>
  <prevImage/> 
  <isLastImage>false</isLastImage> 
  <isNextImage>true</isNextImage> 
  <firstImage>images/codev_new_logo.jpg</firstImage>
   etc.....
</image>
```

Solr XML

```
<doc>
 <field name="id">MA147LL/A</field>
 <field name="name">Apple 60 GB iPod with Video Playback Black</field>
 <field name="manu">Apple Computer Inc.</field>
 <field name="cat">electronics</field>
 <field name="cat">music</field>
  etc.....
</doc>
```

there is a possible way to know which is the equivalent field in this two XML?

Answer (score 1):

These two are completely unrelated.
You need to define your own fields with the corresponding field types in [schema.xml](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml)
The fields would have the name as required by your Collection and would define how the field would behave i.e. if indexed, stored, multivalued etc ....
Field type associated to the fields would defined how the fields would be analyzed during query and index time.